# Order relation notation $\succeq$

Tags: notation, relations, order-theory

My main concern is with the notation around order relations, specifically the use of $\succeq$, I briefly outline relations more generally to set up my thinking. But the questions really starts at the **bold 4**. Thanks!

1. Binary relations on a set $X$ or between two sets $X$ & $Y$ can be denoted by the general form $xRy$.

- These relations will have certain properties such as transitivity, reflexivity etc.

2. Using this general notation $xRy$ we would then have to define the condition of the relation, and the set/sets they are onto e.g.

- $x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \ xRy$ if $x+y \in \mathbb{N}$

3. In some cases the notation itself defines the relation e.g. $x>y$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

**4) There are classes of relations that share certain properties. E.g. Order relations, who all share Transitivity.**

5. **My question** is whether $\succeq$, $\preceq$ function as general notation for order relations, just as $R$ does for Binary relations as a whole, or if they can only be used to define specific order relations.
6. I have seen this notation by the [same lecturer](https://youtu.be/hDBnU_Pun60?t=1077) in the following contexts:

- $x \succeq y$ be used to describe a **(Weak) preorder.** (i.e. transitive and reflexive)
- $x \succeq y$ to discribe preferences in Economics e.g. $x \succeq y$ if $U(x) \ge U(y)$ Where $U$ is the Utlity function s.t. $U:X \to \mathbb{R}$ i.e. this is a **(Weak)preorder + Completeness**.
- $\succeq$ on $\mathbb{R^n}$,    **x** $ \succeq $ **y** if $x_i \ge y_i, i = 1..n$ I.e. a **Partial order**, transitive, reflexive, and antisymmetric - (He noted this was a notation choice, and in a later lecture he noted that in general $\ge$ is [used](https://youtu.be/MKw73XmVJq8?t=1370) for relations that are antisymmetric i.e. Partial Orders.

**Solution 1:** $x \succeq y$ is used as a general notation like $xRy$ for when we are referring to order relations specifically.

- If so could I define the Total order relation in the following way?
- $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,   $x \succeq y$ s.t. $x\ge y$ (seems silly and redundant but you get my point).
- And for a (Strict)preorder: $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,  $x\succ y$ s.t. $x \gt y$

**Solution 2:** $x \succeq y$ is used only for partial orders and (Weak)preorders. This could make sense as technically a partial order, is a (weak)preorder + Antisymmetry in the same way that a Total Order is a partial oder + Completeness. (But by this logic I should be able to use it for total orders also?)

Very much looking forward to feedback, thanks!

Comment: I believe $\succeq$ is used in many different contexts for different things that "Are a bit like $\geq$ but not exactly the same". I suggest you always say what you mean when writing  $\succeq$ and do not assume it has a generally accepted concrete definition. Usually it at least is transitive and reflexive, and _not_ symmetric (though not necessarily antisymmetric).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @student91 so, sadly it's as vague as I thought it was...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892452/what-is-the-difference-between-%e2%89%88-and-%e2%89%83/2892469#2892469

Comment: Note in particular the possible distinction between $\prec$ and $\preceq$, often implying that $\prec$ would be a strict order while $\preceq$ would be nonstrict... much like the distinction between $<$ and $\leq$.  In the end, notation means whatever the author intends it to mean... and $\preceq$ is a particularly generic symbol usable in any context in which we wish to describe an order different than a usual one.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks as well for your reply, greatly appreciated! So if you could best summarise would you say my Solution 1 is correct? And that the use of the notation has guidelines but not hard and fast rules. Thanks!